# Getting the enclosed content

Tags: python, regex

I want to get the enclosed content. Split is only allowing me to split by one delimiter.

Input:

```
\x02\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\x03\x02\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\x03\x02\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\x03
```

Wanted Output:

```
['\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\','\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\','\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx\']
```

Please help. Thanks.

Comment: Can the `\xxx\xxx\xxx\xxx` ever contain `\x02` or `\x03`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `re.split()` from the [re module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html) that allows you to split on a pattern. Something like `filter(None,re.split(r'\\x0\d',s))` should work.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you'll need to say more about the possible variations in input, but this code would work for the specific case you mention:

```
line = '\x02\xxx\xxx\xxx\x03\x02\xxx\xxx\xxx\x03\x02\xxx\xxx\xxx\x03'

if line.startswith('\x02'):
    line = line[4:]
if line.endswith('\x03'):
    line = line[:-4]
chunks = line.split('\x03\x02')

print chunks

>>> ('\xxx\xxx\xxx', '\xxx\xxx\xxx', '\xxx\xxx\xxx')
```

If every line started with '\x02' and ended with '\x03', this simpler approach would work:

```
line = line[4:-4]
chunks = line.split('\x03\x02')
```

If there's much variation in the delimiters, I like root's suggestion to look at the re.split() method: http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split.

Comment: Sorry, should have tested that :) If you add an 'r' in front of the string, like ``r'\x02...`` that will prevent Python raising a ValueError. The 'r' prefix tells Python to treat the string as a "raw" string, and it doesn't interpret backslashes as escape characters.