# Python 3: Splitting by \x0 as a delimiter in a string

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string

```
 s = 'ABC \x03\x04 DEF \x05'
```

and I want to split it such that I extract only the "ABC" and "DEF" part.
After looking at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14229741/getting-the-enclosed-content) I ran the solution, but somehow it is not able to split it.

```
s = 'ABC \x03\x04 DEF \x05'
re.split(r'\\x0\d', s)
['ABC \x03\x04 DEF \x05']
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could improve your pattern a bit and use

```
re.split('[\x01-\x1f\x7f]+', s)
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that there are no `\` in your input string `ABC \x03\x04 DEF \x05` they are actual characters of

```
CODE    HEX     CHAR    
3       \x03    ETX  End of text
4       \x04    EOT  End of trans.
5       \x05    ENQ  Enquiry
6       \x06    ACK  Ack.
7       \x07    BEL  Bell
8       \x08    BS   Back space
```

I believe there are part of the character set called [control characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control_character)

So you need use those character sets as your split chars..

```
re.split(r'[\x00-\x08]', s)    #If you don't want those characters in your results.
re.split(r'([\x00-\x08])', s)  #If you want the characters in your results.<br>
```

This is to be understood similar to `[A-Z]` or `[a-d]` or `[\x03-\x08]`

Of course take due care of what characters you want in your use-for-split-set.